# GUI runs on netbeans IDE but crahes when running jar (AbstractMethodError & NUllPointerException)

Tags: java, netbeans, nullpointerexception

I built a GUI using netbeans, and when I run it using its jar file, after few actions it gets stuck, throws an `AbstractMethodError` and then a lot of `NullPointerException`s. This happens in a random way and after several times of choosing an item from a `JComboBox`, or editing a text in a `JTextPane` component. When I run the GUI through NetBeans, it works fine without errors. The jar also runs fine on a different computer (with the problem happening less often).

Do you guys/gals have any idea about what is the source of this problem, or what could I do to find it?

The stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Ljava / io / PrintStream;) V
at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.processException(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.processException(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: We guys/gals only would be able to help if  you post relevant code...

Comment: Have you tried doing "Clean and Build?"

Comment: The code is very long and uses several defined classes. I don't know where the problem occurs, so I don't know which part of the code to post.
I did try "Clean and Build", but it didn't help. Also I noticed that when running the GUI.jar on a different computer (same Java version) the problem seems to happen les often.